# can't get value of another property when calling helper through Html.EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a html helper, 
if I call it like this:

```
Html.MyHelper("Prop1")
```

I can get the data of another property like this:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString MyHelper(
            this HtmlHelper html,
            string prop){
    var p = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(html.ViewData.Model).Find("Prop2", false);
    if (p != null) value = p.GetValue(html.ViewData.Model);
}
```

but if call it like this:

```
Html.EditorFor(x => x.Prop1);
```

the template contains this:

```
<%= Html.MyHelper(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(""), ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue) %>
```

than I can't get the value of Prop2, anybody knows how to get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the model object or create a new model object to pass in

```
Html.EditorFor(x => x, "Prop1");

Html.EditorFor(x => new Prop1Model { X = Model.Prop1, Y = Model.Prop2 }, "Prop1");
```